# filtering Dictonaries in array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Here I want to filter dictionary in the array which contains the "cate = subcat"
could anybody help me please

```
 menuArr :(
        {
        Cate = subcat;
        Description = "Grilled Chicken";
        Id = 2;
        Image = "http://asaraa.com/our_development/restaurant/admin/logo_image/large/28322grilled_chicken.jpg";
        Name = "Grilled Chicken";
        Price = 0;
        Qty = "";
        Title = "grilled chicken";
    },
        {
        Cate = product;
        Description = gravey;
        Id = 12;
        Image = "http://asaraa.com/our_development/restaurant/admin/logo_image/large/27166mutton.jpg";
        Name = gravey;
        Price = 50;
        Qty = 1;
        Title = gravey;
    },
        {
        Cate = product;
        Description = "Chicken Korma";
        Id = 15;
        Image = "http://asaraa.com/our_development/restaurant/admin/logo_image/large/77845Indian_chicken_recipes.jpg";
        Name = "Chicken Korma";
        Price = 99;
        Qty = 1;
        Title = "Chicken Korma";
    },
        {
        Cate = subcat;
        Description = "Chicken Sandwiches";
        Id = 16;
        Image = "http://asaraa.com/our_development/restaurant/admin/logo_image/large/67831chicken-sandwich-melt-0204_300.jpg";
        Name = "Chicken Sandwiches";
        Price = 0;
        Qty = "";
        Title = "Chicken Sandwiches";
    }
)
```

Comment: r u using a json response ?

Comment: s sir, I am using the Json Response

Comment: Use comparison Predicate for filtering array,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *searchString = @"subcat"
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Cate = %@",searchString];
NSArray *array = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if (array.count > 0)
{
// here goes your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Linq to ObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#where) you can filter it as follows:

```
NSArray* itemsInCategory = [menuArr where:^BOOL(id dic) {
    return [[dic objectForKey:@"Cate"] isEqualToString:@"subcat"];
}];
```

This finds all the dictionaries where Cate=subcat.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSPredicate`

```
NSArray *filtered = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Cate LIKE[CD] %@)", @"subcat"]];
```